# Magento2 admin URL showing 404 page

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I have installed magento2.1.7 as a standard installation. And installed with SSl certificate, the frontend is loading but admin is showing 404, we have enabled the .htaccess. Any thoughts for this?

Comment: Please let us know the URL which you are trying with?

Comment: have you checked your admin page url is it correct? Check from env.php

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 saves current admin panel path in app/etc/env.php.

Please check the admin path under **`frontName`** element:

```
'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin',
  ),
```

Please use `http://<your-website-url>/<frontname-value>` to access your website's admin panel.

Comment: This is also not working dude

Answer (score 0):

Open your PHPMyAdmin from your host try once this SQL command.

**Run this SQL:**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

**Source :**

https://tejabhagavan.blogspot.in/2015/12/after-install-magento-admin-page-shows.html